# how to create profile images collections/groups/stacks in android for group conversation

Tags: android

How can I create image stack like the one in the following image:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ksH2IlIQm9Snbj9B7Gb-_o8xpqOcuLfu_5Jm9_YyaEmcQNnWcDqyzQiEpPkGhghviSN1=h900

I am using android horizontal listview:
https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView but I did not like the way it organizes the image. How can I arrange/stack images like the one in the image.

Comment: Do you mean the round profile icons stacking one over the other ?

Comment: yes. Is there any library for the same?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. I can think of 2 ways of accomplishing that: (1) CustomDrawable (fast and light); or (2) Custom RecyclerView.LayoutManager (very flexible). Both require quite some amount of custom logic. I've never coded a LayoutManager before, so I probably would make a custom view.

Comment: it's easy to make without library...

Answer (score 0):

It's easy creating your own adapter. Step by step.

1) Add your parent Views. Add HorizontalScrollView and FrameLayout(FL) in it. Set gravity to FL: Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT. Now your child view holder - it is FrameLayout.

2) Add first view (in your case ImageView or RoundedImageView) to your FrameLayout. All image should have same size.

3) All your Views have same size. So next step - calculate marginLeft parameters for every next View. And that is all.

**Calculate next view parameters.** Ex. your ImageView size is = 45dp. You added first view with marginLeft = 0; Next tour adding ImageView with marginLeft = 45dp - 10dp (just as example). So next ImageView stacking to first on 10dp. Next View you add with marginLeft = (45dp - 10) + (45dp - 10dp). And so on.

**Ex. calculate formula for every next view: N * (IMAGE_SIZE - STACK_PADDING)**

Comment: @jason let me know, when you try this solution. It's  should be not difficult.

Comment: it will be different for different devices. The resolution and size will change everywhere.

Comment: how can I use dimens effectively or how does it work? Can you please share any link .Thanks